# How to restart protractor instance with a new session?

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, protractor

I need to create a new protractor session in my test.

I tried:

```
browser.get()
browser.quit()
browser.get()
```

But it returns an error:

> Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

Also I tried to use browser.createSession(), but it returns me:

> has no method 'createSession'

So, I need something like restartBrowserBetweenTests options, but I want to call in any part of test. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Using Multiple Browsers in the Same Test](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/25aec6cac875b8b8e9a11a4cf5099c113359faa6/docs/browser-setup.md#using-multiple-browsers-in-the-same-testFork), you can fork a new driver instance:

> If you are testing apps where two browsers need to interact with each
>   other (e.g. chat systems), you can do that with protractor by
>   dynamically creating browsers on the go in your test. Protractor
>   exposes a function in the browser object to help you achieve this:
>   `browser.forkNewDriverInstance(opt_useSameUrl, opt_copyMockModules)`.
>   Calling this will return a new independent browser object.

```
newBrowser = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
```

---

[`browser.driver.createSession()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.createSession) could also be relevant depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but its not exactly what I don't want to work with new webdriver object, I want to redefine browser object. Also I don't know to create session for new browser instance, because browser.browser.createSession returns 'no such method'

Answer (score 0):

In our case we got the error

> Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

when using

```
browser.restart()
```

But in one of our test page objects there was a `static` variable pointing to a `ElementFinder` object.

```
// This line caused the error once the browser was restarted
private static readonly elementToFind = element(by.xpath("<someExpression>"));

// we changed it to
private elementToFind: ElementFinder = element(by.xpath("<someExpression>"));
```

Conclusion: **Check your code for `static` usage.**